# What is the ordering of $post sections in a kickstart file

Tags: fedora, rhel, kickstart

I am exploring **Fedora/RHEL** Kickstart files. I would like to know what is the ordering for the `%post` sections in a kickstart file.

If there are two `%post` sections like the following:

```
%post --nochroot
%end
%post
%end
```

How are they executed ?

**Are they executed in the order the interpreter finds them in ? Or is there some other ordering ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are executed in the same order they appear in the kickstart file. From [RHEL documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/performing_an_advanced_rhel_installation/kickstart-script-file-format-reference_installing-rhel-as-an-experienced-user):

> **Script section count and ordering**
>
> All sections except the command section are optional and can be present multiple times. When a particular type of script section is to be evaluated, all sections of that type present in the Kickstart are evaluated in order of appearance: two `%post` sections are evaluated one after another, in the order as they appear. However, you do not have to specify the various types of script sections in any order: it does not matter if there are `%post` sections before `%pre` sections.